# Wemos modem sleep and sending data every 5 minutes

Tags: arduino, influxdb, esp8266

I built a project where I send data from wemos to influxdb via mqtt. Since the project is solar powered I need to reduce the power consumption. I want my wemos to read data from my sensor every 3 seconds, store the data locally and then switch on the wifi to send the data, every 5 minutes. I already programmed everything but I don't know how to store my data before sending them.
Any idea?

Comment: Which Wemos do you use and how much data do you collect in that 5 minutes?

Comment: Looking through the [ESP8266 Arduino documentation](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), how do you think you might store data?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to collect data at every 3 seconds, then it maybe better to use [ESP-Now](https://www.espressif.com/en/products/software/esp-now/overview) protocol or [nRF24 modules](https://lastminuteengineers.com/nrf24l01-arduino-wireless-communication/) to setup a peer-to-peer master-slave communication network and send the short burst of the data to the master that connects to a server. You can then put the ESP8266 in deep sleep in between the 3 seconds interval.

Both ESP-Now and nRF24 utilise 2.4GHz frequency but does not establish a WiFi connection (which take several seconds).

I have an [example](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/05/esp-01-range-test-with-esp-now-protocol/) of using two ESP-01 with ESP-Now and sending sensor data to a master that is 200m away (with direct line of sight).